# If $q^n$ is irrational for all $n>1$, then $q$ is irrational.

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation, irrational-numbers

**Theorem.** Let $q \in \mathbb{R}$ an arbitrary given number. If $q^n$ is irrational for all $n>1$ integer, then $q$ is irrational.

**My Questions.** What is a the name of this statement and what is the shortest proof for it? Thanks.

Comment: If $q$ were rational, then $q^n=q\cdot\ldots\cdot q$ ($n$-times) were rational for each $n\in\mathbb N$, since the rational numbers form a field.

Comment: Is $n$ an integer?

Comment: It's enough that $q^n$ is irrational for _any_ integer, positive or negative.

Comment: Your statement is worthless unless you change the `if` to `iff`. Under the current version, you might as well say that if $q^2$ is irrational then $q$ is irrational (in other words, it's the other direction which is interesting here).

Comment: @barakmanos: At least this statement is true, the statement with "iff" is false.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I don't know about the opposite direction. That's why I said it might be interesting (I haven't investigated it, but I figured that since the statement was so obvious, OP must have meant the other direction). If this is false, then the entire question is rather redundant.

Comment: @barakmanos: $q = \sqrt{2}$...

Comment: Let me tell you what's going on here: your statement is so obviously true to any mathematician that they can't believe it's really what you meant to ask. (If $q$ is rational, then so is $q^n$  $-$ obviously $-$ for all integers $n$; thus, if $q^n$ is irrational for any integer $n$, then so is $q$.)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: OK, so the interesting question that comes to mind is, for what values of $q$ does the opposite direction hold? I have a feeling that it holds for all transcendentals and only for them.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Second thought, no such $q$ can exist (for any $q$, just choose some rational number $k$, and calculate $n=\log_qk$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rationals $\,\Bbb Q\,$ are closed under multiplication, therefore, by induction

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \ \forall i\!:\ q_i \in \Bbb Q\ \Rightarrow\ q_1\cdots q_n\in \Bbb Q$

${\rm Contrapositively}\qquad\ \ \  q_1\cdots q_n \not\in \Bbb Q\ \Rightarrow\ q_i\not\in\Bbb Q,\ \text{for some}\ i$

$\text{The constant case}\,\ q_i = q\ \ {\rm is}\ \  q^n \not\in \Bbb Q\ \Rightarrow\ q\not\in \Bbb Q,\ $ which yields your claim.

So the result is a contrapositive of the closure of $\,\Bbb Q\,$ under multiplication. Generally, there are no widely-used names for the contrapositive forms of these ubiquitous closure properties. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:242+complementary+view) for many other such "complementary" views of closure properties of algebraic operations.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this trivial? Proof by contradiction.

Suppose $q$ is rational. Then $q^n$ is also rational for all $n>1$. Since the assumption is that they are irrational, the assumption is false and $q$ must be irrational.

Don't know if there is a name for this.

Comment: Don't need "for all $n>1$". It's enough to use $n=2$ (for example). As I mentioned in a comment to the question, this statement is worthless unless you change the `if` to `iff`. Under the current version, you might as well say that if $q^2$ is irrational then $q$ is irrational (cause it's certainly ain't rational). In other words, it's the other direction which is interesting here.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim:
$$\not\exists a\in \mathbb{N}, b\in \mathbb{N} : bq^n = a ~\forall n > 1$$

(or alternatively)

$$\forall n > 1\not\exists a\in \mathbb{N}, b\in \mathbb{N} : bq^n = a$$

A proof:

Using your statement as hypothesis, let's consider $q^2$. You say that $q^2$ is irrational. By contradiction, if $q$ is integer or rational, then:

$$q = \frac{a_q}{b_q},$$

with $b_q \neq 0$.

In this case $q^2 = \frac{a_q^2}{b_q^2}$ must be integer or rational. In fact, both numerator and denominator are integer. This contradicts your hypothesis and then $q$ is irrational too.

Comment: cavalry has come

Comment: I don't understand what it means when $\forall n > 1$ is the very last thing in a statement.

Comment: All the things on the left hold for all n>1 integer...

Comment: So is $\not\exists a\in \mathbb{N}, b\in \mathbb{N} : bq^n = a ~\forall n > 1$ the same thing as $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, n > 1 : \not\exists a\in \mathbb{N}, b\in \mathbb{N} : bq^n = a$, then?

Comment: I think both statements are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this via contradiction pretty quickly. FTSOC suppose that $q$ is not irrational. Then $q$ is rational. Any finite product of rational numbers is rational, so $q^{n}$ must be rational. This contradicts the assumption that $q^{n}$ is irrational for all $n>1$, so $q$ has to be irrational.